# How does : # use perl eval 'exec perl -S $0 ${1+"$@"}' set the perl version?

Tags: shell, perl

I have to debug an old perl script which, apparently, is setting the version of perl in a way which I do not understand...

```
: # use perl
    eval 'exec perl -S $0 ${1+"$@"}'
    if 0;
```

`perl -h` says that `-S` means  "look for programfile using PATH environment variable".  `$0` is the current program.  And I've read that `$@` means "The Perl syntax error message from the last `eval` command." But why are they adding 1 to that ?  And how does this all fit together ?  What is it doing?

Part of what I have to debug has to do with the fact that it's picking an older version of perl that I don't want.  For everything else, we use `#!/usr/bin/env perl` which, I suspect, may be doing the same thing.  I also suspect that my solution may lie in fixing `$PATH` (or preventing the code that's goofing it up from goofing it up).  But I'd like to go at this with a better understanding of how it's picking the version now.

Thanks for any help !

Comment: See [perlvar](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) for the precise meaning of `$@` (but, as Shawn's answer shows, that second line is run by the shell so `$@` is shell's, not the Perl's one.)  A more detailed explanation of the `${1+"$@"}` trick is found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/68488/226064), for example.

Comment: Re "*And I've read that $@ means*", In Perl yes, but Perl never executes that command (because of the `if 0`). That command it executed by a shell (if the shebang line were somehow ignored).

Answer (score 5):

That's intended to run whatever version of perl is first in your path by treating the script first as a shell script that then executes perl. In this context, `${1+"$@"}` is the arguments (if any) passed to the script.

From the bash manual:

> `${parameter:+word}`
>
> If parameter is null or unset, nothing is substituted, otherwise the expansion of word is substituted.

and

> Omitting the colon results in a test only for a parameter that is unset

There's a similar example in [perlrun](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.30.0/perlrun.html):

> This example works on many platforms that have a shell compatible with Bourne shell:
>
> ```
> #!/usr/bin/perl
> eval 'exec /usr/bin/perl -wS $0 ${1+"$@"}'
>   if $running_under_some_shell;
> ```
>
> The system ignores the first line and feeds the program to `/bin/sh`, which proceeds to try to execute the Perl program as a shell script. The shell executes the second line as a normal shell command, and thus starts up the Perl interpreter. On some systems `$0` doesn't always contain the full pathname, so the `-S` tells Perl to search for the program if necessary. After Perl locates the program, it parses the lines and ignores them because the variable `$running_under_some_shell` is never true. If the program will be interpreted by csh, you will need to replace `${1+"$@"}` with `$*`, even though that doesn't understand embedded spaces (and such) in the argument list. To start up sh rather than csh, some systems may have to replace the #! line with a line containing just a colon, which will be politely ignored by Perl.

Using `/usr/bin/env` is another way to do the same thing, yes.

Comment: The `${1+"$@"}` is a workaround for a bug in older shells that would replace `"$@"` with a single empty argument instead of nothing at all when there were no arguments passed in. On modern systems you can just use `"$@"` by itself, but indeed, those same systems will understand `#!` lines and won't need this hack at all.